# When importing a library from multiple contracts, is one library deployed, or multiple ones?

Tags: solidity, libraries

When importing a library from different contracts, is only one library deployed or multiple ones?

Take the following file structure:

- lib.sol
- contractA.sol

```
import './lib.sol';
contract A {}
```

- contractB.sol

```
import './lib.sol';
contract B {}
```

Would there be one instance of lib.sol, or two instances of lib.sol deployed?

Answer (score 2):

With your example, 2 instances of the library will be deployed. The `A` contract will use one, and the `B` contract will use another.

To actually reuse a specific instance of a library, you will need to do some manual work while compiling your contracts.

First, you can deploy the library on its own (it can be deployed as a regular contract).
Then, you will need to compile your contract `A` and `B` using the `solc` compiler in the command line, using the [linker](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#library-linking), and providing the deployed library address.

You can read the docs about linking a deployed library to a contract while compiling it: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#library-linking

Check the library docs here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries